# connecting to Elasticsearch instance on GCP from a nodeJS client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I am using the nodeJs elasticsearch client to connect to an instance hosted on GCP using the cloudId, user and password

```
const { Client } = require('elastic')
const client = new elasticsearch.Client({
  cloud: {
    id: 'i-o-optimized-deployment:dXMtY2VudHJhbDEuZ2NwLmNsb3--------------------------------------------dkMTg5ZTYzNWU3JDkyOGEwYTB***************Mx',
  },
  auth: {
    username: 'elastic',
    password: 'changeme'
  }
})
```

This seems to connecting to localhost instead of the cloudId specified. I tried the https url method and same results with that too. I am able to connecting from pyelastic with the url, user and password.

Is there any additional set for nodeJs?

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Did you manage to connect to the ES Cloud instance?